# Microsoft Read Aloud stops when minimized

Tags: microsoft-word, text-to-speech

Is there a way to keep the reading of Microsoft documentation using its read aloud feature even when minimizing or switching between windows? I think its a bit obnoxious that a use case of moving around the desktop wasn't considered at MHQ when designing this system.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your needs could not be fulfilled currently.

I suggest you submit this question on [Word UserVoice](https://word.uservoice.com/) forum.

As a workaround, please open a new desktop if you need to do other operations.

I do a test, if I click the Task View [image] > Desktop 2, the Microsoft Read Aloud still works.